# iOS 11: Completely replace subviews on device rotation

Tags: swift, ipad, uicollectionview, rotation, orientation

I'm a computer science student trying to get practice with swift. I am implementing a custom master-detail menu in my iPad application. In portrait mode, it is laid out with the master menu horizontal at the top and the detail view directly below it. In landscape mode, I would like it to be laid out side to side with the master menu vertically on the left.

Instead of having two sets of constraints and activating/deactivating them depending on orientation, is it acceptable practice to completely remove the views and replace them with different ones? Meaning I'll have two views for the master menu (vertical and horizontal) and also two views for the detail view. I am achieving this in the `viewWillTransition(to size:with:)` method. Also, do you forsee any problems in the future because of my implementation?

The reason I am doing that is because in portrait mode, the detail view consists of a collectionView nested in another, which allows horizontal swiping between pages and vertical scrolling through the content. But in landscape mode, it makes sense for the detail view to only have vertical scrolling through content. So to me, it seemed easier to have two different views for portrait and landscape orientation.

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

P.S. I am not using IB

Comment: having 2x versions of the same view and removing/replacing does not seem very efficient resource-wise nor coding-wise. What is your reasoning for not wanting to manipulate constraints instead?

Comment: My reasoning is that the behaviour of the views in landscape vs portrait mode is slightly different so it might be more complicated to try to define different behaviours for each case